# Deploying Ruby on Rails app on Nginx Puma localmachine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, puma

Hi I am trying to deploy RoR app using puma as application server and Nginx. Iam following tutoril available here: 
http://codeonhill.com/rails-capistrano-puma-nginx-on-vps/
Sorry Being a newbie in deployment, I want to ask whether we can deploy Rails app using Nginx as reverse proxy on local machine?

Secondly after wasting an entire day i could able to deploy it sucessfully

```
user@username-VirtualBox:~/Rails/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu/testapp$ bundle exec puma -b unix://tmp/testapp.sock
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on unix://tmp/testapp.sock
* Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1490292608378-29275
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And when i am trying to access this url iam getting google search result. How to access my application over there?

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Jeremie I am trying to access this url unix://tmp/testapp.sock